# dropdown in IE8 cuts item text

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a dropdown user control on my page. I have not set width for dropdown. Dropdown is setting its width automatically. But in IE 8 for longer text in dropdown items, text gets cut.
The same dropdown renders perfectly in IE7 and Firefox. Is it IE8 issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This is a known Microsoft issue."

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=405681#details

Comment: thanks Romina. That saved my lot of time to troubleshoot the issue.